# How to write lengths of time

Tags: time

I have searched for how to write lengths of time, but all I have found is how to write what time it is.

Let us say that we wanted to fully write out the length of a movie. The Revenant is 2h 36m. Would we write, "The Revenant is two hours, thirty-six minutes," The Revenant is two hours thirty-six minutes," or "The Revenant is two hours and thirty-six minutes?" How would adding seconds look?

The most common way I have seen it written is without the comma, but I have seen the "and" in there also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just write:

> The Revenant is two hours and thirty-six minutes.

(though everybody who knows The Revenant is a movie will know what you mean).

You need to write

> The *length* of The Revenant is two hours and thirty-six minutes.
>   The *duration* of The Revenant is two hours and thirty-six minutes.
>   The Revenant is two hours and thirty-six minutes *long*.

(thanks @k1eran for the *long* option)

If you need to add seconds, it will become a list with three items:

> The length of The Revenant is two hours, thirty-six minutes, and forty-five seconds.

(the last comma, the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), can be omitted).

Comment: *The Revenant is two hours thirty-six minutes **long.*** sounds simplest to me.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valuable addition.